# Why ion-fab-button doesn't stay fixed inside ionic 4 popover?

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, position, popover

I'am developing an ionic 4 application and I've created a popover.
Inside this popover I want to use a `ion-fub-button` that has to be fixed in the top-right position of the popover.

The HTML code that I've written is like this:

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
        <ion-fab-button (click)="getStats()">
            <ion-icon id="closeBTN" name="stats" color="light">
            </ion-icon>
        </ion-fab-button>
   </ion-fab>


   <div>
      ......
   </div>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see, I want that the ion-fab-button should stay FIXED in the top-right position of the popover, but in reality it doesn't stay fixed, but scrolls with the rest of the content.
May anyone tell me why and how I can fix it?

I've also tried to insert the button inside a ion-header, but also the `ion-header` scrolls with the rest of the popover. And I've also tried to use css `position:fixed` for this button, but it doesn't work.

May anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

**This works for me on 25-02-2021 with Ionic 5**

*html*

```
 <div class="fixed">

        <ion-fab vertical="top" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
          <ion-fab-button size="small">
            <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
          </ion-fab-button>
        </ion-fab>

      </div>
```

*css*

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: It also works in Ionic 6. Thanks Sampath!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [this link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12252) will help you. In my case, if `ion-fab` is placed in the custom component inside `ion-content`, fixed property not work properly.