# SrollToTop method doesn't work with a component in Ionic 6/Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have made a fabbutton so the user can scroll to top in one click. I have test this without a component and this was working fine. Now I want to use this fabbutton as a component, because I want to use this in multiple pages.

This my component setup:

**fabbutton.component.html**

```
<div class="fixed">
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button class="toolbar-color" size="small" (click)="scrollToTop()">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</div>
```

I use a custom css class to make it stick when the user scrolls

**fabbutton.component.scss**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 0;
}
```

[Why ion-fab-button doesn't stay fixed inside ionic 4 popover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56260058/why-ion-fab-button-doesnt-stay-fixed-inside-ionic-4-popover)

This is working fine.

Now I have method to scroll to top in the ts file.

**fabbutton.component.ts**

```
export class FabbuttonComponent {

  @ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) content: IonContent;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
  }

}
```

I use the selector like this in my homepage.

**Home.html**

```
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content color="secondary" [scrollEvents]="true">
    <app-fabbutton></app-fabbutton>
  </ion-content>
```

I also inject the component in the home.module file.

When I test the app I get the following error:

> core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'scrollToTop')
> at FabbuttonComponent.scrollToTop (fabbutton.component.ts:14:18)
> at FabbuttonComponent_Template_ion_fab_button_click_2_listener (template.html:3:56)
> at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15031:1)
> at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15069:1)
> at HostElement. (platform-browser.mjs:466:38)
> at _ZoneDelegate.push.3484._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:443:1)
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25595:1)
> at _ZoneDelegate.push.3484._ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:442:1)
> at Zone.push.3484.Zone.runTask (zone.js:214:1)
> at ZoneTask.push.3484.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:525:1)

I have tried to use the method as a parent and child method but it doesn't work. How can I use the component method into the injected page? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/920cagns/

Comment: Please post complete code, not just fragments.

Comment: Hello, @E.Maggini this is my full code. Have a look in the jsfiddle link.

Comment: It doesn't work because IonContent is not a child of your component. It is in the parent.. Please post complete code. Where is app.component.ts for example? This is where you must pass in a reference to IonContent as an input. Alternatively, you could transmit the event back up. But without complete code, it is difficult to give a proper solution.

Comment: I have nothing in my app.component. I inject this my component in the hom.module.ts file. There I import the component in the declarations tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the scrollToTop() method on the fabbutton.component.html like this:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <ion-fab (click)="scrollToTop()" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" edge slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button class="toolbar-color" size="small">
      <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
</div>
```

After testing this it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access ion content (parent in this case) from fabbutton (child element).
You have to add an EventEmitter to fabbutton and do the scroll from home.ts

fabbutton.component.ts

```
...
export class FabbuttonComponent {

  @Output('onClick') onClick = new EventEmitter();

  scrollToTop() {
    this.onClick.emit() ;
  }

}
```

Home.html

```
...
<app-fabbutton (onClick)="scrollToTop()"></app-fabbutton>
...
```

Home.ts

```
...
@ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) content: IonContent;

scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
}
...
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for you time. I have tried this solution also including yours. When I click the button it doesn't work. It only works when I don't use a component. I get no error in my dev console.

Comment: @Fearcoder have you imported `EventEmitter` from '@angular/core'? try also removing `{ static: false }` from ViewChild declaration

Comment: Hello @Talon, Thanks for your time. I imported the EventEmitter like this: `import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';` and changed the child to `@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;`. No errors in dev and stil doesn't work :(